# How to catch a text only but ignore a text with an element?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to catch the text inside the `.test` but i want to ignore the `<span>` element with the NEXT text inside.

I tried doing something like :

`$('ul.antrian > li.test:not(:has(span.badge))').text();`

The code above not giving me any text inside `li.test`, i just want to catch a 0004 text, but not the `span.badge` one inside `.test`.

How could i do that ?

```
<ul class="list-group antrian" style="font-weight:bold">
    <li class="list-group-item test">
        0004
        <span class="badge">NEXT</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `console.log($('.test').clone().children().remove().end().text())`

Comment: Another `$('.test').contents().first().text()`